# Requesting information from running C# server with ASP.NET MVC3 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an application with the following properties:

- A client has a machine on a network with a piece of C# code that gathers details about the machine it is running on and periodically sends these details to a little server I wrote in C#
- The details of the client are then displayed to someone by viewing the server command line
- There can be multiple clients at once

What I would like is for this application to instead of displaying the details to the server command line, is to instead display them on an ASP.NET MVC 3 page.

I am thinking of either a) in the client getting it to remotely update a database with the new details and cutting out the server all together (however this may cause a huge amount of overhead it there are multiple clients running at one), then get the ASP.NET application to query the database or b) Make a new method in the server that once called, will return a list of the currently connected clients and their last submitted details then get my controller in ASP.NET to call this method and display the details?

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Seems like MVC and Entity Framework. Expose a Web API (that the clients push to) and a webpage (that displays what the API collected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use as much as possible that which the MS stack provides you with (IIS instead of your own server) and keeping it as simple as possible (e.g. try not to write your own server).

A variation of option A would be the most optimal I believe. But instead of having the client directly saving it into your DB, let them send it to your Web API as a means of having some layer which can validate stuff, or change data where needed.

This same Web API would be able to return data to other clients which have been stored in your DB.

Try this tutorial to get you started:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Answer (score 0):

This is different than what I will be writing shortly for my MVC application, which is going to render data such as the number of visits by all users and current user when a controller Action (Web Page) is requested, but as Kay states, I would look into IIS to collect this information although you may be able to incorporate an ApiController that just collects the data (JSON) from the client machines sort of an event listener. Without knowing exactly why and what data you are requesting from the client machines it is difficult to guide you in the right direction. Creating a Restful Web Service using ASP.NET WebAPI would probably be the best choice because you can also authenticate the requests based on user groups (ie: power users) in the AD. For instance, your Web.config file would contain

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
       <allow roles = "PowerUsers"/>
       <allow roles = "Administrators"/>
       <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
....
```

This is just a start and I will add content to this as I work on my own project. If you get anywhere please answer your own ? as you have peaked my curiosity and I love cats.